# Is there a simple and direct way of using audio as an output for a program?

Tags: c++, html, audio, web-audio-api

I want to try some C and C++ programming with audio processing, such as synthesizers, chorus, delay etc, but I only know working with a console as output. I wish to have, instead of a console application, a window that would be capable of sending an audio signal to the speakers, running the code at the background and working with it in a similar way as it goes with printf: every time I would call the "output function", it would send to the speakers (or sound card) a sample value, indicating current oscilator position. This output operation could be executed every time it is requested or in the end of a built in loop. Doing all this with a high sample rate would be just great.

I think I could do all this using AudioWorker on Web Audio API, plus a flexible GUI on HTML5 canvas, but I'm new at this API and I'm not sure whether its resulting sound quality is good enough.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I use Windows 8.1, but any answer for other platform is welcome.

Edit2: Any programming languages other than C, C++ or JavaScript suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: C++ and html5 are pretty different.

Comment: You are right, but the programming language is not that relevant, what I really search for is the functionality.

Comment: html5 is not a programming language. Furthermore, different programming languages may have different functionality. All in all, combining C++ and html5 is a bad idea. I'm voting to close your question.

Comment: I don't want to combine C++ and html5, I expressed my self in a wrong way when I stated that I want to use C or C++, those are the languages I use most, but what I was trying to explain that I want a simple way of process an input in a program and then use the output as an audio signal. This may be a naive question, but this space isn't only for experts. After explaining what I want to do, I mentioned that it seems I can do it with Web Audio API.  This is the reason that C++ and html5  appear at this post. I just want to generate an audio signal, sample by sample, from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do lots of sound synthesis with the Web Audio API and I think it sounds great. Javascript is really all you need. Well, if you want to use audio files, you need a web server to serve those audio files, but the audio synthesis all happens in javascript.

It doesn't matter so much what OS you use, but different browsers have different levels of support for the web audio API. Chrome tends to have the best support, and Internet Explorer definitely has the worst support.